# Help to learn this LPP sample

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I'm with many difficulties to understand a LPP.

This is the problem:
[image]

This is the Tableau:
[image]

After the first iteration:
[image]

After the second iteration:
[image]

Until here I understand everything, but...

This is the solution:
[image]

I can't understand the numbers of the solution.

The Pivot Value from second iteration, before the solution is `-5`? It is the less number, why the `5/3` it is the Pivot Number instead `-5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find pivot row (after you determine pivot column), one must consider the ratios of constants by pivot column elements and select the smallest ratio. Consider the pivot column $x_5$:
$$\frac{8}{\frac{5}{3}}=4.8 \ (1) \\
\frac{0.5}{\frac53}=0.3 \ (2) \\
\frac{3}{-5}=-0.6 \ (3)$$
However, if the ratio is negative, it is ignored. So, $(3)$ is ignored and $(2)$ is the smallest ratio.

Comment: OMG! So the correct Pivot is 0.3 and no -0.6, Thanks!